# how to make reverse the recursion after recursion in Java

Tags: java, recursion

The goal is to print out half of the length of the previous line until it reaches 0 and then reverse it. For example, if the original size input is 5, the result is:

```
*****
**
*

*
**
*****
```

So I wrote a program like

```
void print(int size) {

    if (size == 1) {
         System.out.print("*");
         System.out.println();           
    }

    if (size > 1) { 
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
        size = (int)(size/2); 
        print(size);
    }
}
```

The result comes out with

```
*****
**
*
```

What is the best way to use recursion to reverse the result(the second part)?

Thanks

Comment: Put the print loop after you call `print(size)` as well as before it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You implement printing only on one way. When your code achieve end of stack
nothing happens. Read more about how recursive actually work, and what happend when your call methods recursive.

Best way(based on your code) to achieve your goal is:

```
static void print(int size) {
    if (size == 0) {
        System.out.println();
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();

        print(size / 2);

        //when stack ends point of execution will go to next statement
        //(stack ends when size==0, after that will be performed  size==1, and size=2, size== 5, eop)
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you!

Comment: @user2029709 I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You existing method prints the stars first and then visit the next recursion level, which is like the **first order traverse** in traversing a binary tree.

To reverse the result, you just need to use **"post order traverse"** - visit the next recursion level first, then print.

In the following example, I moved the `System.out.print("*")` statements after the `print(size/2)` statement. It should achieve what you want.

```
static void print(int size) {
    if(size==1){
        System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println();
    }

    if(size>1){
        print(size/2);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the accumulator as identity and proceed

```
void printReverse(int ident, int size) {
    if (ident <= size) {
        // quick hack , on the border case change it to the odd int
        if (ident < size && ident * 2 > size) {
            ident = size;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < ident; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
        printReverse(ident * 2, size);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive function could take two inputs:

```
void print(int _current, int _start){

    if(_current < -_start){
        return;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < Math.abs(_current); i++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
    if(_current > 0){
        print(_current/2, _start);
    } else if(_current == 0){
        print(-1, _start);
    } else{
        print(_current * 2, _start);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
In you case, the "main" call would be print(5, 5);

Comment: It will print four asterisks instead of five in the second group.

Answer (score 0):

Use `StringBuilder` to build your strings and `Stack` to collect them for the reverse output:

```
static void print(int size, Stack<String> stack) {
    if (size == 1) {
        System.out.println("*");
        stack.push("*");
    } else if (size > 1) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            sb.append("*");
        }
        String s = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(s);
        stack.push(s);
        print(size / 2, stack);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();
    print(5, stack);
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(stack.pop());
    }
}
```